# WCF client - can not determine correct binding for WCF web service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have been trying to connect to a publicly available web service https://tsteracun.posta.si/ERacunService/Service.svc which seems to be implemented with WCF (at least that is how it looks like to me).

However whichever binding configuration I use I am unable to make the connection.
Two common errors I get are:

- BadContextToken
- An error occurred when processing the security tokens

I am using VS2010 with .NET 3.5SP1 and I've simply added the service URL as a web service.

Comment: What binding's have you tried?  Are you able to add the service via the Add Service Reference dialog?  Glancing at the WSDL it looks like `wsHttpBinding` should work, with a security mode of `Transport`.

Comment: I apologize for taking so long to answer the issue was that the server required messages encrypted with specific certificate. Once I used the appropriate certificate it started to work OK.
Thank you for the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the server required messages encrypted with specific certificate. Once I used the appropriate certificate it started to work OK.